# Delay scheduling docusign

Tags: docusignapi

How to delay scheduling docusign using java?

I tried with set scheduling sending status as "started"
Workflow status as "scheduled"
Envelope definition status as "created"
Response getting status as created but is not schedule.

Answer (score 0):

You can delay the envelope by a certain amount of time or have it proceed on a specific date time. You add a workflow object to your envelope request:

```
14 "workflow": {
15          "scheduledSending": {
16              "rules": [{
17                  "resumeDate": "'"${SCHEDULED_DATE}"'" 
18              }]
19          }
20      },
```

(ignore the line numbers)

See [docs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/recipients/scheduled-sending/)
and [example](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/schedule-an-envelope/)

You still set the envelope to "sent" status

Comment: I tried with above code which you mentioned but is also not working